# Coq proof stuck in a loop

Tags: coq, proof, lambda-calculus

Edit : It was a newbie mistake. I missed out on the case beta_equivalence (Var x) (Application (Abstraction 0) Var x). Please refer to this question instead :

[Loop while proving a theorem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66916376/loop-while-proving-a-theorem)
Thanks!

I am trying to prove the following theorem after formalizing lambda calculus with Debruijn indices and substitution in Coq.

```
Theorem atom_equality : forall e : expression, forall x : nat,
  (beta_equivalence (Var x) e) -> e = (Var x).
```

and these are the definitions for expression and beta_equivalence

```
Inductive expression : Type :=
  | Var (n : nat)
  | Abstraction (e : expression)
  | Application (e1 : expression) (e2 : expression).
.
.

Inductive beta_equivalence : expression -> expression -> Prop :=
  | beta_1step (x y : expression) : beta_reduction x y -> beta_equivalence x y
  | beta_reflexivity (x : expression) :  beta_equivalence x x
  | beta_symmetry (x y : expression) :  beta_equivalence x y -> beta_equivalence y x
  | beta_transitivity (x y z : expression) : beta_equivalence x y -> beta_equivalence y z -> beta_equivalence x z.
```

I am stuck in a loop while trying to prove this theorem.

```
Proof.
intro e. induction e.
  - intros. inversion H.
```

After applying these steps, these are the hypothesis and subgoals I've to work with

```
4 subgoals
n, x : nat
H : beta_equivalence (Var x) (Var n)
x0, y : expression
H0 : beta_reduction (Var x) (Var n)
H1 : x0 = Var x
H2 : y = Var n
______________________________________(1/4)
Var n = Var x
______________________________________(2/4)
Var n = Var n
______________________________________(3/4)
Var n = Var x
______________________________________(4/4)
Var n = Var x
```

I can solve the first subgoal by "inversion H0" tactic and second subgoal by "reflexivity". However when I reach the third subgoal, this is what I am left with

```
1 subgoal
n, x : nat
H : beta_equivalence (Var x) (Var n)
x0, y : expression
H0 : beta_equivalence (Var n) (Var x)
H1 : y = Var x
H2 : x0 = Var n
______________________________________(1/1)
Var n = Var x
```

This is exactly what I started with. If I apply inversion on H or H0, it will open up the same 4 cases again. I am new to coq and might be making a newbie mistake. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This theorem is just... not true? `beta_equivalence (Var x) (Application (Abstraction (Var 0)) (Var x))` (`v = (\x -> x) v`) but the expressions are not equal. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah... You are absolutely correct. Maybe I shouldn't have rushed to post this doubt. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.