# Loop while proving a theorem

Tags: coq, proof, lambda-calculus, theorem-proving

I am trying to prove the following theorem after formalizing lambda calculus with Debruijn indices and substitution in Coq.

```
Theorem atom_equality : forall e : expression , forall x : nat,
  (beta_reduction (Var x) e) -> (e = Var x).
```

and these are the definitions for expression and beta reduction

```
Inductive expression : Type :=
  | Var (n : nat)
  | Abstraction (e : expression)
  | Application (e1 : expression) (e2 : expression).
.
.

Inductive beta_reduction : expression -> expression -> Prop :=
  | beta_1step (x y : expression) : beta_1reduction x y -> beta_reduction x y
  | beta_reflexivity (x : expression) :  beta_reduction x x 
  | beta_transitivity (x y z : expression) : beta_reduction x y -> beta_reduction y z -> beta_reduction x z.
```

I am stuck in a loop while trying to prove this theorem.

```
Proof.
intro e. induction e.
  - intros. inversion H.
```

After applying these steps, these are the hypothesis and subgoals I've to work with

```
3 subgoals
n, x : nat
H : beta_reduction (Var x) (Var n)
x0, y : expression
H0 : beta_1reduction (Var x) (Var n)
H1 : x0 = Var x
H2 : y = Var n
______________________________________(1/3)
Var n = Var x
______________________________________(2/3)
Var n = Var n
______________________________________(3/3)
Var n = Var x
```

I can solve the first subgoal by "inversion H0" tactic and second subgoal by "reflexivity". However when I reach the third subgoal, this is what I am left with

```
1 subgoal
n, x : nat
H : beta_reduction (Var x) (Var n)
x0, y, z : expression
H0 : beta_reduction (Var x) y
H1 : beta_reduction y (Var n)
H2 : x0 = Var x
H3 : z = Var n
______________________________________(1/1)
Var n = Var x
```

This is exactly what I started with. I will have to prove that y can only take the value of Var x for H0 to be provable.

(beta_1reduction is the one step beta reduction of lambda calculus, and beta_reduction is its reflexive, transitive closure)

Comment: Would you please also add the definition of `beta_1reduction` to make your code a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You are stuck because inversion on `H` is not enough. Instead, you would need a kind of induction on `H` to provide you with the needed hypothesis in the transitive case, to allow you to conclude.
However, since `H`'s type is an inductive predicate, induction on it is tricky. Indeed, if you use the usual `induction H.`, Coq will lose all informations about the indices in `H`'s type, and especially the `Var x` one. This will make your proof attempts fail.

Instead, what you can use is rely on the `dependent induction` tactic (you will need to `Require Import Program.Equality` to have access to this tactic). This tactic automatically handles the kind of induction on inductive predicates where the indices are not variables. Here you could start your proof with `intros e n H. dependent induction H.` and the rest should be easy.

In general, when you define inductive predicates (such as `beta_reduction`) over inductive datatypes (such as `expression`), and you want to use hypothesis using those inductive predicates (here `H`), doing induction directly on the predicate (using `dependent induction`) as we did here is very powerful. In particular, it specializes which constructors of your datatype can appear in the inductive hypothesis, thus in a way performs a kind of induction on the datatype at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

@Meven's answer is a good explanation of what is wrong and gives a good solution.  If you want to do it without the `dependent induction` tactic, you can `remember` the lost information yourself.

```
Proof.
  (beta_reduction (Var x) e) -> (e = Var x).
  intros e x H.
  remember (Var x) as q eqn:Hq.
  induction H; rewrite Hq in *. 
  - inversion H.
  - reflexivity.
  - rewrite IHbeta_reduction1 in IHbeta_reduction2.
    apply IHbeta_reduction2.
    reflexivity.
    reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Comment: Indeed, and this is pretty much the magic that `dependent induction` automates behind the scene.